# Ошибка Django: OperationalError: no such column

Tags: python, django

Появляется вот такая ошибка при отображении шаблона:

[image]

Подскажите, как можно устранить эту ошибку.

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from PIL import Image

class Post(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   text = models.TextField()
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
   published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)
   image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images')

 def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

 def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: Добавить отсутствующий столбик в таблице в базе данных

Comment: @andreymal, а как можно это сделать?

Comment: А для этого нужно знать, что вы творили с моделями. Наверно, вы когда-то добавили image к модели поста и забыли создать и выполнить миграцию?

Comment: @andreymal, дополнил свой вопрос файлом models.py. скажите пожалуйста, про какую именно миграцию вы говорите?

Comment: https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/migrations.html

Comment: @andreymal, окей, большое спасибо за подсказку, сделал миграцию и сайт ожил. впредь буду помнить о миграциях.

Answer (score 2):

`https://stackoverflow.com/a/61095891/13209546`

Перевел на русский по просьбе комментатора.

Около суток пытался решить проблему, уже думал сносить, как все писали на всех источниках, Базу, но перед сном подумал, что, возможно получится таким способом.

Чтобы добавить в вашу существующую базу данных необходимую таблицу(у меня это была account_profile), необходимо для начала скачать «`DB Browser for SQLite`» и проделать следующее:

1. Скопируйте уже имеющуюся ‘db.sqlite3’ в какую-нибудь папку.
2. Удалите ее из папки с проектом.
3. Запустите «`python3 manage.py make migrations`», затем «`python3 manage.py migrate`».
4. Откройте вашу новую базу данных в «DB Browser for SQLite».
5. Затем вам необходимо экспортировать ‘account_profile’-таблицу как CSV файл. Показано в image1(снизу комментария)
6. Затем удалите вашу новую ДБ и закиньте обратно старую
7. Откройте теперь вашу старую ДБ в  «DB Browser for SQLite», нажмите «Файл»—>«Импорт»—>«Таблицу как файл CSV» и выберите ваш CSV файл(как раз в нем и содержится необходимая таблица)
8. Затем вы увидите, что в таблице столбцы называются как ‘field1’ и  ‘field2’, переменяйте их в ‘id’ ’user_id’ соответственно. Показано на image2 и image3
9. Затем можно либо удалить в базе данных админа, либо посмотреть, какой у него id и вписать(например у админа id-5, пишем в столбец ‘id’ - ‘1’, в столбец ‘user_id’ - ‘5’)

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

[image: Результат]

Comment: Если будут вопросы, с радостью отвечу. Вопрос с проблемами в изменении пользователей немного освоил...

Comment: В случае с photo_image, нужно будет будет посмотреть в таблице, которая отвечает за ваш пост посмотреть, как прописан столбец с photo_image и скопировать. 
Если не поможет, то: 
1. Закомментируйте вашу строку с models.py.
2. Пропишите 'python3 manage.py makemigrations' и 'python3 manage.py migrate'
3. Затем пропишите 'python3 manage.py migrate --fake'.
4. Раскоментируйте строчку с 'photo_image'.
5. Пропишите снова 'python3 manage.py makemigrations' и 'python3 manage.py migrate'

Answer (score 0):

Вручную добавьте столбец. На примере sqlite3 это будет выглядеть так:
В консоле, либо линукс терминале запускаете sqlite3 с указанием пути к файлу БД

```
    sqlite3 db_name
```

Убедитесь, что работаете с нужной базой:

```
    .database
```

Подготовте изображение, и укажите к нему путь при добавлении столбца:

```
    ALTER TABLE blog_post ADD COLUMN image VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT 'images/blog_posts/IMG_5503.JPG' NOT NULL;
```

Убедитесь, что колонка добавлена в таблицу:

```
    PRAGMA table_info(blog_post);
```

Закрываем sqlite3:

```
    .exit
```

Далее создаем миграции:

```
    ./manage.py makemigrations blog_post 
    ./manage.py migrate
```

Все работает, только что в существующую бд (с данными) добавил колонку в таблицу, миграции прошли, в модели появилось поле для выбора изображений, а к уже существующим обьектам было добавлено изображение по умолчанию
'images/blog_posts/IMG_5503.JPG'.

Убедитесь, что статика работает исправно и путь к файлу ('images/blog_posts/IMG_5503.JPG') изображения существует.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема не в шаблоне. Судя по скриншоту, ваша переменная `posts` — это ленивый QuerySet, который лезет к базу данных за постами только при первом обращении к нему, и так получилось, что `for post in posts` в шаблоне и оказалось этим самым первым обращением. В итоге шаблон обращается к базе данных, и вот это вот обращение падает из-за отсутствующего столбца в таблице, который был прописан в модели.

Модели лишь описывают, как следует интерпретировать таблицы и столбцы и связанные с ними данные, которые хранятся в базе данных, но никак не управляют этими самыми таблицами и столбцами в базе данных. Если в модели было добавлено или удалено поле, то соответствующий столбец не будет изменён в самой базе данных автоматически. Вообще, автоматически это делать невозможно по различным техническим и логическим причинам, а вот полуавтоматически можно — для этого существуют миграции.

Краткая суть такова: при изменении модели запускаем `makemigrations`, джанга смотрит изменения модели и пробует угадать, какие изменения нужно сделать в базе данных (чаще всего угадывает правильно, но не всегда); миграция сохраняется в файл, после чего уже изменяем саму базу данных согласно прописанным в этой миграции инструкциям, запустив команду `migrate`.

Подробности обо всём этом в официальной документации: https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/migrations.html (перевод)

Comment: Шаблон не обращается к базе данных. К базе данных обращаются например функции из view

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич обращается. Переменная `posts` — это объект QuerySet, который ленив и достаёт объекты из базы только при первом обращении к нему. Соответственно, цикл `for post in posts` из шаблона оказывается этим самым первым обращением и тем самым провоцирует запрос к базе данных, который и падает. (Это вы что ли минусы ставите, не разбираясь в том, как работает Django?)

Comment: Могу легко привести пример кода, когда первое обращение к базе будет происходить еще во view. Согласен, что это не всегда оптимально, но в вопросе нет функции view, и однозначно сказать, что всегда работает как написали Вы нельзя

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич да, есть много всяких разных случаев, когда QuerySet полезет в базу данных ещё в view (я сам его часто специально дёргаю в view, чтобы он гарантированно обращался к базе не при рендеринге шаблона). Но всё-таки в данном конкретном случае он полез в базу во время рендеринга шаблона) Это можно однозначно сказать по скриншоту, представленному в вопросе.

Comment: Впрочем, дописал уточнение в ответ во избежание недоразумений в будущем

Comment: Например, если нужно вывести информацию о том, сколько времени назад было написано сообщение. Берем поле published_date именно во view, так ведь гораздо проще, чем городить огород в шаблоне? Согласны?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич это уже не касается данного вопроса