# Django - фильтр данных

Tags: python, django

Я получаю данные из базы примерно так.

```
client = Client.objects.all()
```

Есть способ фильтровать уже полученные данные, не обращаясь к самой модели?
Ну например вот так.

```
client = Client.objects.all()

client.filter(meta_data=None).filter(expire_date=datetime.datetime.now().date())
```

Стоит задача фильтровать данные по динамически выбранным пользователем полям.

Comment: Можно, но в большинстве случаев это ещё более затратно по ресурсам, чем обращение к БД. Не совсем понятна ваша конечная цель...

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич цель такая - есть произвольные параметры запроса, id  клиента или его имя и т.д. изначально не известно по какому признаку будет идти фильтрация, поэтому я не могу использовать одно обращение к бд, а строить отдельный запрос к бд для каждого сочетания параметров как то не очень выглядит

Comment: Есть более правильное решение, без этих заморочек. Примите правку вопроса. :)

Comment: Что-то я всё равно не понял логики, почему вы не можете использовать одно обращение к бд?

Comment: @andreymal Добавил ответ. Одно обращение к БД использовать можно.

Answer (score 1):

Из обсуждения вопроса я понял, что Вы хотите фильтровать данные по динамически выбранным полям.

Ваше решение не выглядит наиболее оптимальным.

Django позволяет делать выборку из модели даже по динамически выбранным полям.
Всё дело в том, что **filter** работает как

```
filtered = queryset.filter(**dict_container)
```

Соответственно, *dict_container* Вы можете сформировать динамически еще до запроса к БД.

Например, так:

```
def your_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Здесь будут Ваши имена фильтров
    filter_names = ('filter_one', 'filter_two', 'another_one', )
    filter_clauses = [Q(filter=request.GET[filter])
                      for filter in filter_names
                      if request.GET.get(filter)]
    if filter_clauses:
        queryset = Client.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, filter_clauses))
```

Это лишь пример, как это можно использовать.

Comment: Строго говоря, в коде из ответа (как, впрочем, и из вопроса) нет вообще ни одного обращения к БД :)

Comment: @andreymal а как же Client.objects.filter ?    Я так понимаю, что Client это модель. Согласен, что теоретически в filter_clauses может ничего не оказаться :)

Comment: Весь написанный код всего лишь создаёт объект QuerySet, который ленив и сам по себе ничего не загружает, а реальное обращение к БД осуществляется лишь по первому обращению к самому его содержимому, [возможно даже не в view, а уже внутри render_template](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707966). Если этот ваш `queryset` больше не трогать, то в итоге обращение к БД так никто и не сделает :)

Comment: А, так я вам же это всё уже и разжёвывал в том вопросе... -_-

Comment: @andreymal согласен. Но в любом случае концепция в ответе будет работать быстрее и оптимальнее.